# Pointer to array of structures - explanation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm just learning C and I have this code, which defines two structures in C:

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char *name;
} Object;

typedef struct {
  unsigned size;
  Object *items;
} Array;
```

I'm not sure what happens there and how can I work with those structures.
Is it true, that structure Array contains array of structures Object? If so, how? I don't see any square brackets here.
Can someone explain what is happening inside? Not sure about pointers.
How can I for example initialise structure Array, which will contain amount of structures Object depending on size?
Do I have to use malloc or realloc? If I use alloc in function, how can I free it later, if I don't know, how many times I have called that function containing malloc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` contains a *pointer* to `Object`, which can be used to point to a dynamically-allocated array, like so:

```
Array arr;
arr.size = 10;
arr.items = malloc( sizeof *arr.items * arr.size );
```

Each `arr.items[i]` has type `Object`, so you can set the `id` and `name` members like so:

```
arr.items[i].id = 1;
arr.items[i].name = malloc( strlen( "foo" ) + 1 );
if ( arr.items[i].name )
  strcpy( arr.items[i].name, "foo" );
```

When you're done, you'll need to make sure you free each `arr.items[i].name` before freeing `arr.items`:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < arr.size; i++ )
{
  free( arr.items[i].name ); // assumes memory for arr.items[i].name was
}                            // allocated with malloc, calloc, or realloc
free( arr.items );
```

If `arr.items[i].name` is set to point to a string literal or an `auto` array, such as

```
arr.items[i].name = "foo";
...
char some_array[] = "bar";
arr.items[j].name = some_array;
```

then you would *not* want to call `free` on those items.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it true, that structure Array contains array of structures Object?"
No it isn't. Structure Array contains a pointer, not an array. To create an arry you have to allocate memory with `malloc` or `calloc` and then assign it to this pointer.

"If I use alloc in function, how can I free it later, if I don't know, how many times I have called that function containing malloc?"
There is `free( void* ptr )` to clean the memory you've allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`. Have a look here for example - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/

If you want to have an array inside you must have something like this

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned size;
  Object items[10];
} Array;
```